# Comments show path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is what I have in my comments controller:

```
def show
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
end 

private

def find_commentable
  params[:commentable_type].constantize.find(params[:commentable_id])
end
```

In my users controller:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
    @comments =  @user.comments.find(:all, :order => "id desc", :limit => 20)
  end
```

In my user show:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
<%= truncate(comment.body, length: 100) %>
<%= link_to "Expand comment", post_comments_path(comment) %>
<% end %>
```

When clicking on the link I get this error:

```
undefined method `constantize' for nil:NilClass
```

These are the highlighted lines:

```
def find_commentable
  params[:commentable_type].constantize.find(params[:commentable_id])
end
```

The url I am taken to is:

```
/15/comments
```

When I need to be going to:

```
/2/comments/15
```

2 being the post id and 15 being the comment id. How do I get this working?

The comments path:

```
post_comment GET    /:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show


 @commentable = find_commentable
  @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment])
```

Comment: Where are you calling `find_commentable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
<%= link_to "Expand comment", post_comments_path(comment) %>
```

Look at your `rake routes` and see what the actual parameters it's using.  You can pass them like so:

```
post_comments_path(post_id: post_id, id: comment_id)
```

Or another way is simply use the order

```
post_comments_path(post_id, comment_id)
```

Then in your controller you should actually use these id's:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
```

Since you only want the comment and you have its id, you can ignore the post id and just do this in your controller:

```
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
```

And then call it like this:

```
post_comment_path(id: comment.id, post_id: 0)
```

Comment: I apologize, I didnt provide the path, just edited the answer, unfortunately none of these work.

Comment: Sorry, I needed to know the path variables. I updated it to match them! Hope it helps

Comment: Actually this might not help, what you're still missing is `params[:commentable_type]`. But I don't know in what context that is being called. If it's a before filter then you can just pass the params the same way as I specify above (`commentable_type: "some-type"`)

Comment: Sorry, i'm a bit confused. I'm using commentable_type because I have multiple commentable models. Is there any other code I post that will help?

Comment: Well I don't see what is calling `find_commentable`, and that's what's giving the error. But I do know that method needs you to pass along more params then what you currently pass in the `link_to`

Comment: My create method within my comments controller is calling the method, added the code now

Comment: This is what i'm getting: undefined local variable or method `params' for UsersController:Class

Comment: Have you updated your users controller since the original problem? (specified in your question) And is this problem replacing that one?

Comment: Ok, so now I put updated that controller code and put it in my show method in my users controller and now i'm getting: Couldn't find Product without an ID

Comment: Would you be willing to take this into one of thoese chatbox things?

Comment: Haha I was just looking for how to do that manually, apparently at some point SO will create one for us

Comment: Haha, I think I just need to add a few more comments!

Comment: I just made one anyways: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50224/katie-hs-question-discussing